# On click VS onitemtouchlistner for recylerview

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a click event for recylerview whose items are movie poster. When user clicks on the item of recyclerview, another activity should be started.
What would be the best way to do it? Creating onClickListner inside ViewHolder or using onItemtouchListner?

Comment: Refer to [Here](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/defining-item-click-listener-for-recyclerview-in-android/)

Comment: If the `movieStuffObject` can be used repeatedly, then having a single `onItemTouchListener` shared in the `ListView` will have greater efficiency, and is usually easier to maintain after development halts and continues... from experience, `List`s with less than 70 items have no impact on speed, however, when this goes over 100~200, then some rendering is lost, during fast scrolls.